# move from QTP to selenium , can anyone help me to find a framework for reporting purposes

Tags: selenium, automation, qtp

my company want to move from QTP to selenium , can anyone help me to find a framework for reporting purposes i just need to make sure when the step is failed there is a report to till me that :)
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you must understand that unlike QTP, Selenium is NOT a test tool. It is just a library to allow automation of a web browser. It does not provide an assertion mechanism, test runner, reporting, etc that commercial tools like QTP do.

Instead, you have to combine Selenium with a test framework library. These are platform specific and will provide you with methods to structure tests, make assertions and create reports.

There are many options such as RSpec (Ruby), Cucumber (Ruby/Java), NUnit (C#), TestNG (Java), and many, many more.

Comment: thanks for the replay , i just want to make a POC project in the  selenium. i used the TestNG for my project put also in the first  failure the whole project stops i also used the ATU framework which is  pretty good but also it doesn't support a step status [Pass/fail] yet .

Comment: I prefer stopping on the first failure but I know that you can change TrstNG to continue you failure.  I haven't used it in a while so couldn't tell you an exact answer