# Qtp to Selenium Equivalent methods

Tags: java, selenium, qtp

I am trying to convert Qtp library to selenium.

I need all the equivalent methods of qtp in selenium.I have list of qtp methods that need to be converted into selenium. Please help me

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119997/move-from-qtp-to-selenium-can-anyone-help-me-to-find-a-framework-for-reporting

Comment: I have gone through the post earlier but it doesn't serve my purpose.I need equivalent methods in selenium like we have webbutton().CheckProperty  in  Qtp i want its equivalent method.

Answer (score 0):

We can write checkProperty() method in selenium,But this method will works for only checkboxes and radio buttons.

Call checkProperty method in @Test by passing driver, and attribute of the radio button or check-box element:

```
 checkProperty(driver, "checked","true");
```

Below is the method to check weather the element is selected or not.

```
    public void checkProperty(WebDriver driver, String propertyName, String propertyValue){

      boolean isSelected = driver.findElement(By.xpath(your_xpath)).getAttribute(propertyName).equals(propertyValue); 

      if(isSelected){

         s.o.p("Radion button / checkbox is selected");

      }else{

         s.o.p("Not selected");

      }   

}
```

if the element contains checked attribute otherwise it will throw `nullPointerException`. If there is no checked attribute, you directly check using `driver.findElement(locator).isSelected()`.

Comment: This is specific to radio button.there are lot of other properties that can be passed to it like status ,enabled etc.

Comment: selenium don't have methods which are similar to QTP. If we want to use same methods, then we have to write our methods which has similar functionality. Only few of the methods are similar in Selenium.